# SSH session closed during apt upgrade, and is prompting for input. What are my options to continue?

Tags: ssh, apt, upgrade

I'm viewing `/var/log/apt/term.log` because the ssh session closed while it was running and my `apt-get upgrade` is prompting for input, but because I'm viewing the log I can't give input. What are my options to proceed? Posted below is a photo of the predicament.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To finish the upgrade, which had reached the setup phase, run

```
dpkg --configure --pending
```

You might need to run the upgrade again too, if the package upgrades were split into multiple sets.

If either of these complains about locks, kill any running `dpkg` and `apt-get` processes and try again. (They would typically have been killed when the SSH session terminated.)

Then install `screen` or `tmux` and use them to run your upgrades in the future, that way you’ll avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill it and run it again.
Next time use termux or non-Interactive

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt -y ...
```